# The number of new hats never gets higher than 99

Tags: bug, top-bar, winter-bash

It seems the maximum number shown as a badge on the snowflake is 99:

[image]

From my calculations, it should've shown something like 150 when I made that screenshot. It shouldn't be that hard to show more digits; this is done for the green reputation indicator as well.

Comment: How the heck did you get that many hats? O_O

Comment: Stop cheating then ;)

Comment: Dear sir, please donate some hats to the poor (which is me). :P

Comment: @Mithrandir So now we know that Glorfindel has 170 Fascinator hats.

Answer (score 15):

[image: "Doctor, it hurts whenever I do this." -- "Then don't do that."]

Comment: Is that a [status-declined]?

Comment: @Glorfindel Nah, just a snarky response ;) You have a point -- with the new top bar you can fit three digits. The two-digit restriction is because in previous years, three didn't fit.

Comment: Wait, is this the only picture of TB as the Doctor where he isn't wearing his hat?