# Can we please get the full count of new hats now?

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, winter-bash

If you have earned more than 99 hats since you last checked the hat inbox, the counter gets limited to 99:

[image: 99 new hats]

There should have been around 300 new hats there, by my count.

The 2-digit restriction is there because of [historical reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304538/the-number-of-new-hats-never-gets-higher-than-99#comment989983_304549):

> @Glorfindel Nah, just a snarky response ;) You have a point -- with the new top bar you can fit three digits. The two-digit restriction is because in previous years, three didn't fit. – balpha Dec 15 '17 at 16:33

And obviously there's room for more digits - for instance, in the inbox counter:

[image: 32188 inbox items]

So... could I have my ridiculously overblown new hat numbers, please?

Comment: I know this isn't relevant, but exactly how? 300 new hats???

Comment: @DonThousand - I ran a script that checks my flagging statistics on every site, which had the side effect of... visiting every site and meta site, which gave me a hat on every site.

Comment: Oh my lord! LOL

Comment: You are a legend. :D